# Framed text in a Graphics expression

Tags: graphics

How is it possible to insert `Text` inside `Framed` as below?

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], Text[Style["cross-section", 14]]}]
```

[image]

```
Framed["cross-section", RoundingRadius -> 5]
```

[image]

That is, I want the `Text` inside `Graphics` to be "framed".

Comment: I don't understand, haven't you tried? `Text[Framed@Style["cross-section", 14]]` works well...

Comment: Actually you can use pretty much anything in `Text`.  It seems to be very very similar, near-identical, to `Inset`.  But they do take different arguments.

Comment: @Kuba: I don't know why I didn't try this combination. Actually the graphic I wanted to create was more complicated and somehow I was lost:-)! I was sure it is rather trivial. In any case, thanks a lot. `Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], 
  Text[Framed[Style["cross-section", 14], RoundingRadius -> 5], {0, 
    0.5}]}]` does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Szalbocs: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}], 
  Inset @ Framed["cross-section", RoundingRadius -> 5]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Anyway to not to use Inset. It's bit difficult to control relative sizes with Inset.