# Frame around text or MaTeX?

Tags: graphics, text, matex

This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure out how to do it or any documentation of it.

How does one add a frame (not an outline, but a frame) around `Text` or `MaTeX` inside a `Graphics` object?

Comment: Wrap it in [`Framed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Framed.html)?

Comment: Can you give an example? Not sure what "it" refers to.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment by @Kuba to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98616/framed-text-in-a-graphics-expression),

```
Graphics[{Green, Disk[{0, 0}],
  Thick, Blue, 
  Text[Framed@Style["cross-section", 12, Black], {0, 1/2}]},
 ImageSize -> Tiny]
```

[image]